# OpenCV , CRT: Improve Memory Leak detection

Tags: c++, opencv, crt

I'm using openCV 2.4.10 and Visual Studio 2013. After closing my App in Debug-Mode. I get a lot of stuff like this

{237} normal block at 0x00000000004CF790, 48 bytes long.

Data:  47 65 6E 65 72 61 6C 69 7A 65 64 48 6F 75 67 68

{236} normal block at 0x00000000004CF710, 16 bytes long.

Data: <  L             > E0 FA 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

{235} normal block at 0x00000000004CF690, 16 bytes long.

Data:  47 65 6E 65 72 61 6C 69 7A 65 64 48 6F 75 67 68

{223} normal block at 0x00000000004CFA20, 48 bytes long.

Data:  47 65 6E 65 72 61 6C 69 7A 65 64 48 6F 75 67 68

...

The "leaks" aren't growing so it seems to me, it is caused by static allocation in the OpenCV libs i'm using.

My Problem is, that i can easily miss real memory leaks in this mess of false positive. Therefore i want to improve the output.

I can think of two solutions:

1.) Exclude magically the libs from the CRT-Report

2.) Get for every memory leak filename and line

for 2) I tried the following

- using visual leak detector didn't improve
- added _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

both didn't work. Have someone a suggestion.

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx#BKMK_Heap_State_Reporting_Functions

Comment: `47 65 6E 65 72 61 6C 69 7A 65 64 48 6F 75 67 68` is "GeneralizedHough". I'm not sure if it's a clue.

Comment: fyi: Finding Memory Leaks Using the CRT Library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

Comment: i know how to use CRT in generell: but i've memory leaks from third-party libraries. And i don't know how to get more information out of the dll